# SFTP to HP-Nonstop

Tags: node.js, hp-nonstop, tandem

I am trying to create a nodejs client to sftp files from a remote HP-Nonstop server, just wondering whether this is possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Bombora (the only node.js deep port I know of for NonStop) then you should be able to run the OSS sftp client.

Alternatively if there are any node.js sftp packages out there (I googled up a few) then you should be able to use them.

If you don't have TNS/X hardware then you are out of luck, I don't think there is a node.js implementation on TNS/E.

Andy

Comment: Thanks Andy this means if my client is making request from outside NonStop environment I should be able to use sftp to access files held on server.

Comment: Aha - so your client isn't on the NonStop. Shouldn't be a problem, the sftp server on the NonStop is pretty normal. Bear in mind that there are two file system types on the NonStop, ones is posix like (OSS), the other is proprietary (Guardian), but can (mostly) be addressed using posix type file names.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your comments